# Clearing Focus does not work

Tags: android

Today i found some posts about how to celar the focus of an EditText.
It was recommed to do this:

Set focusable and focuableInTouchMode to true for the parent layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calc_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

And to use this in the DialogFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.textEditCalcInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.calc_input);
        this.textEditCalcInput.clearFocus();

        view.findViewById(R.id.my_layout).requestFocus();
    }
```

But unfortunately this does not work. The textfield always has the focus when the ui appears.

So how to remove the focus?

[image: Portrait with Keyboard up and AlertDialog up]

[image: Landscape with Keyboard up and AlertDialog (in Background)]

Here i want the AlertDialog to be shown and the Keyboard to be hidden.

Comment: Did you try adding an id to the linearlayout, finding it and then requesting focus? Maybe for some reason it is not working with the view you get in the onViewCreated.

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I edited my post to show what you recommed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in LinearLayout use:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Note that you can also use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

in AndroidManifest.XML.

Another solution is adding

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

to onCreate of the Activity in order to hide keyboard whenever the activity starts.

Comment: This is quite close to a solution. There is one problem left when i manually set the focus to type in text and then rotate the screen to landscape. The keyboard does not hide then but i want it to. Its a DialogFragment.

Comment: Im sorry that wasnt 100% correct. it does hide. it does not hide when the keyboard is up, an alertdialog is in the front and i then rotate the device to landscape. i implemented the alertdialogs not to disappear when the device rotates.

Comment: first, Which of the above solution you used? second, does the keyboard is in invisible mode when it's not in landscape mode, and when you rotate the screen it appears?Because if it's not visible, rotation should not makes it invisible, unless you touch other area except of edittext

Comment: I used the last one: `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` i corrected my last comment using another comment. it hides perfectly. it just does not hide when an AlertDialog is in the front and i then rotate the device. The AlertDialog is kept open on rotation (like i want it to).

Comment: Try using `dialog` instead of `this`
`dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_A‌​LWAYS_HIDDEN);`
If it didn't help, would you please paste the screenshot of your application here,

Comment: I added to photos of my device. the first shows the portrait mode when keyboard and alertdialog are up. the second shows what happens when i then rotate the screen. the alertDialog is somehow behind the EditText and Keyboard but i cant make any input because it is up. Strange behaviour.

Comment: adding: `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to the EditTexts solved it. i anyway accept your answer because its a good solution for most of the usecases and you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

and if doesn't work try this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration mConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(mConfig);
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    switch(orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //hide keyboard 

            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

           //do whatever you want
            break;
        default:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            //do whatever you want

            break;
        }
}
```